# k8s ingress path match not working as expected

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

According to nginx path match policy: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/

Path Priority¶

In NGINX, regular expressions follow a first match policy. In order to enable more accurate path matching, ingress-nginx first orders the paths by descending length before writing them to the NGINX template as location blocks.

My rules are defined like this:

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: some-lb
  rules:
    - host: "example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: cs-stage-backend
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: cs-stage-frontend
                port:
                  number: 80
```

So, according to the path rule, if I go to **example.com/api/v1/docs** it should go to **cs-stage-backend** and rest all go to **cs-stage-frontend**. But it always goes to cs-**stage-frontend**.

Can anyone please help me if I am missing something?

Comment: can you get the actual resulting configuration from the nginx pods?

Comment: Can you show your ingress spec annotations in your question.

Comment: I do not have access to ingress class... I will try to get the access and update.

Comment: I think you have to use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation.
This link can help : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md

Comment: The rules look fine for NGINX ingress, and you shouldn't need to use the rewrite-target annotation for this. The only thing that looks suspect is the `ingressClassName: some-lb`. Do you actually have an ingress class named "some-lb"? Does it work if you switch to `ingressClassName: nginx`?